# Not able to read XML using CFHTTP in Coldfusion 2016

Tags: xml, web-services, coldfusion, cfhttp

I am trying to read XML feed from this [URL](https://architechsfortheweb.com/blogfeed/) using cfhttp tag in coldfusion

and i an using this code for it

```
<cfhttp url="https://architechsfortheweb.com/blogfeed/" method="GET" resolveurl="Yes" >
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/xml ">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="mimetype" value="application/xml" />
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept" value="application/xml ">
</cfhttp>

<cfset feedData = CFHTTP.FileContent>
<cfset xmlData = XMLParse(feedData)>
<cfdump var="#xmlData#">
```

[image]

please help me with this, already wasted so much time on this
please help me and et me know what is my mistake

Comment: I ran that code locally and it returns the RSS feed perfectly using CF 10. Which version are you using? Are you running it locally?

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno CF 2016,0,11,314546

Comment: It looks like you got a 404 error. (Maybe switch the user agent as the default "ColdFusion" may be blocked.)  Have you considered using the built-in CFFEED tag?https://cfdocs.org/cffeed

Answer (score 1):

Your existing code works fine as-is. You're getting a 404 issue that I'm not getting. The suggestions of the header would be valid if I wasn't using the same header and didn't get a 404. Can you reach that URL in your browser? Maybe the site has blocked you for some reason?

Using James' suggestion of `<cffeed>` makes it easier. It converts the XML to a struct that is easier to parse.

```
<cffeed source="https://architechsfortheweb.com/blogfeed/" name="xFeed" />
<cfdump var="#xFeed#">
```

[image]